# Require help in hiding AWS Lambda inline code

Tags: security, aws-lambda

For Privacy and security reasons, I would like to hide my aws lambda function code.

To Disable the following abilities:

- The ability to edit lambda code inline.
- The ability to download a lambda deployment package

My code is less than 5 MB (So 10 MB concept is ruled-out)
I can't create any IAM role, As most of the admins are superior users than me.

**Adding more details**

- Security Threat - Anyone who has access to the account can modify my
  code
- Privacy - I don't want other peep into my code unnecessarily

TIA

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to "hide" your lambda function code? Is this a business requirement to protect intellectual property? Have you considered putting the Lambda function in a different AWS Account? Please edit your question to provide more information about what are wanting to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added additional details to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are other users in the same AWS Account that have Admin capabilities, then it is not possible to "protect" your code. They would be able to access and modify the code. (Hopefully you are also keeping your code in a repository for safety and maintenance purposes, so that would need to be protected, too.)

An alternative would be to **put the AWS Lambda function into a different AWS Account,** then provide cross-account permissions that allow the function to be invoked but not otherwise accessed.